# Select2 4.0 - Push new entry after creation

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have been using Select2 4.0.0-rc.1 for a couple of weeks (using the `ajax` adapter) and I am trying to find a way to "push" data after it has been initialized.

Within the dropdown list, I have the choice to

- select an entry in the list (using `ajax`)
- add a free entry (using `createTag`)
- add a new entry

If I select "add a new entry", I can fill out a form, and once saved, the new data must be shown as a selected entry.

If I push data using `select2_existing.select2( { data: data } ).val( 4 );` it works, but `ajax` call does not work anymore.

I have then to

1. destroy select2
2. re-create it

Which will then allow me to have my new data and `ajax` adapter working.

It is possible to do this without the create->data->destroy->create cycle?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be able to push a new selected option by creating a new `<option selected>` tag with the information you are looking to display.

```
<option value="id" selected="selected">text</option>
```

Once you append this `<option>` to the original `<select>`, you are going to need to trigger the `change` event so Select2 (and other components) are aware that the value changed.

```
$element.trigger("change");
```

So putting it all together in JavaScript

```
var $element = $("select"); // the element that Select2 is initialized on

var $option = $("<option selected></option>"); // the new base option
$option.val(newOption.id); // set the id
$option.text(newOption.text); // set the text

$element.append($option); // add it to the list of selections
$element.trigger("change"); // tell Select2 to update
```

Comment: This does not work for me on v4.  Options removed, but .trigger('change') does not re-draw and pick up new options

Comment: awesome thanks @kevin after trying everything this worked for me