# Select2 Load On Demand Dropdown set selected value in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2-4

I am using Load On Demand Dropdown in Select2. I need to set the dropdown value selected using jquery. I was trying the below code but It doesnt seems to be working. Anybody have any idea about how to achieve this.

**Code**

```
$("#ddl").select2("data", { id: 1, text: "India" });
```

Comment: can you show this issue on fiddle ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select2 4.0 - Push new entry after creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058625/select2-4-0-push-new-entry-after-creation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to set the selected value for Select2 remote dropdown. Use the below code to make it working.

**Code**

```
var $element = $("#dropdown ID");
var option = new Option(value, id, true, true);

// Append it to the select2 dropdown element
$element.append(option).trigger("change");
```