# How can I set options from a checkbox as selected in select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a list of check-boxes. When a user selects them and click the send e-mails button, a modal opens with a form to fill.

That form has a select2 field listing emails by AJAX from database.How to default select those options that were previously ticked in check-box?

```js
function formatRepo (repo) {
  if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

  var markup = '<div class="clearfix">' +
      '<div class="col-sm-5">' + repo.nome + '</div>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-10"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> ' + repo.email + '</div>' +
      '</div>';

  return markup;
}

function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
  return repo.nome || repo.email;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.emails').click(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox][name='id[]']:checked").each(function () {
      $('div.destinatarios select').val($(this));
    });
  });

  $(".destinatarios").select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/clientes/listarAjax')?>",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          busca: params.term
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: data.items
        };
      },
      cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    width: '100%'
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="check">
<a class="btn btn-primary emails" data-toggle="modal" data-placement="top" title="Enviar E-mail" data-target="#emailModel">Enviar E-mail</a>

<select class="col-sm-8 col-lg-8 form-control destinatarios" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select2 4.0 - Push new entry after creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058625/select2-4-0-push-new-entry-after-creation)

Comment: or [Select2 4.0.0 initial value with Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30316586/359284)

Answer (score 0):

just pass them to your modal function for as I don't see any code for your modal function so I will give you an example

from your checkbox you got the values

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

in your modal function

```
function modalOpen(arrayofcheckboxes){

 }
```

when you open the modal use the function like this

```
 modalOpen([1,2,3,4]);
```

Comment: I got the values, I just need them selected at the select2 input.