# Select2 4.0.3 unable to fill other select2 fields using ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I've some problem with Select2, basically i need to fill some other form fields with data retrieved from Select2 Ajax search.

even following example found here:

[Select2 4.0 - Push new entry after creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058625/select2-4-0-push-new-entry-after-creation)

I'm not able to fill some field programmatically with results founds from Select2

Just as example, consider that I've Three fields, i can use two of these fields to search data and i want that other remaining fields will be filled automatically after choosing one of ajax call returned values.

so, as example:

```
 Test field 01 (Select2 field)
 Test field 02 (Select2 field)
 Test field 03 (standard input field)
```

If i search something on "Test field 01" i want that 02 and 03 will be filled automatically.

I've implemented one solution that you can find below but doesn't work with the Select2 fields, only with the input one.

**If i use the code inspector i see that the new option inside the "select" element are correctly created and tagged as "selected" but seem that the "select2-selection__rendered" span element is not correctly update after triggering the "change" event**

**During my tests, I also notice that the the function "updateselect2" that i use to update the data is called four times each time i select one value from results and consequentially i found 4 time the same value in the destination select box.**

take a look at animated gif below to see the complete behavior

[image: problem example]

There is something that i did wrong?

My setup is:

- jquery-3.1.0
- Select2 4.0.3

Below you can find a complete example of my current work:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="select2.min.css"/>    
    <script src="select2.full.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="section ">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="testField01" class="control-label">Test field 01</label>
            <select id="testField01" class="form-control" name="testField01" style="width:150px;">
              <option value=""></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="testField02" class="control-label" >Test field 02</label>
            <select id="testField02" class="form-control" name="testField02" style="width:150px;">
              <option value=""></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="testField03" class="control-label" style="width:150px;">Test field 03</label>
            <input id="testField03" class="form-control" value="" readonly="readonly" />
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var select2_query = {};

function markMatch(text, term) {
    // Find where the match is
    var match = text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase());

    var $result = $('<span></span>');

    // If there is no match, move on
    if (match < 0) {
        return $result.text(text);
    }

    // Put in whatever text is before the match
    $result.text(text.substring(0, match));

    // Mark the match
    var $match = $('<span style="color:red"></span>');
    $match.text(text.substring(match, match + term.length));

    // Append the matching text
    $result.append($match);

    // Put in whatever is after the match
    $result.append(text.substring(match + term.length));

    return $result;
}

function updateselect2(elId, values) {

  var $element = $('#' + elId); // the element that Select2 is initialized on
  if ($element.attr('id') == undefined) {
    return false;
  }
  $element.empty();
  var $option = $("<option selected></option>"); // the new base option
  $option.val(values[elId]); // set the id
  $option.text(values[elId]); // set the text
  $element.append($option); // add it to the list of selections
  $element.trigger("change"); // tell Select2 to update
}


function formatResult(result) {
  if (result.loading) {
    return result.text;
  }
  var term = select2_query.term || '';
  var $formattedResult = markMatch(result.testField01 + ' - ' + result.testField03, term);

  return $formattedResult;
}

function formatSelection(selection) {
  if (!selection.selected) {
    updateselect2('testField02', selection);
    $('#testField03').val(selection.testField03);
  }
  return selection.testField01;
}


function initSearch(fieldId, searchType) {
    $("#" + fieldId).select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "/search/data",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    id: params.term, // search term
                    by: searchType,
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
             params.page = params.page || 1;
                return {
                    results: data.items,
                    pagination: {
                        more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                    }
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
            return markup;
        },
        minimumInputLength: 4,
        templateResult: formatResult,
        templateSelection: formatSelection,
        language: {
            searching: function (params) {
                select2_query = params;
                return 'Searching…';
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('testField01').select2();
  $('testField02').select2();

  initSearch('testField01', 'testField01');
  initSearch('testField02', 'testField02');

});
```

JSON DATA SAMPLE:

```
{"total_count":1,"incomplete_results":false,"items":[{"id":1,"testField01":"123456789","testField01":"987654321", "testField03":"ABCDEFGHIJK"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you append options to an select field, you need to reinitialize the select2 element like:

`$element.select2("destroy");`

instead of `$element.trigger("change");` in the `updateselect2()` function.

Also, the correct way to change the value in select2 is not by triggering the `change` listener, but by invoking `.select2('val', thevalue)` which in your case would not work because of the new options, but keep that in mind.

Another note: No need to initialize the select2 in the document.ready, as initSearch will do it for you.

Last note: your sample json is wrong, you're passing testField01 twice

Comment: `.select2('val', thevalue)` is deprecated in select2 4.0.x, replaced by `.val(thevalue)`

Comment: Good head-up, didn't noticed that as I'm personally still with 3.5.